# Why is setTimeout closing my variables twice?

Tags: javascript

I really don't get it

```
var f = function() { alert('f') };
var g = function() { alert('g') };
setTimeout(f, 2000);
var h = function() { f() };
f = g;
h();
```

Yeah, I know, this is the way it goes and I have to live with it, but I don't see any reason for this. Enlighten me.

PS. Check the subj btfore you answer, I'm doing Python, Ruby and .NET for a living and I've read Crockford. And I even know what the pointer is.

Comment: What does "closing my variables twice" mean?

Comment: +1 to @David Dorward. Don't understand the question. What is the problem?

Comment: @david just run the code in jsfiddle. it's the basic basic "event handler in a loop" thing.

Comment: @synapse: What Is The Question?? What do you mean saying "closing my variables twice"?

Comment: obviously you guys haven't read the PS and have no idea what the closure is and how it works in JS.

Comment: I know exactly what a closure is. I have read the PS. I still don't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @synapse: We know what the closure is, thanks. Is the answer ok for you?

Comment: @synapse: you CALL setTimeout. You give it a ptr.

Answer (score 1):

> I really don't get it

Which bit?

**That your code echoes `g` first?**

When you say:

```
var h = function() { f() };
```

you are not taking the current *value* of `f` and remembering it, you're making a closure containing a reference to the *variable* `f` in the container scope (potentially global scope here).

Change the contents of the variable `f` after that definition, and the value seen by the function `h`, run afterwards, will change. It's identical to the situation with:

```
var a= 1;

function b() {
    alert(a);
}

a= 2;
b(); // 2
```

**That your code echoes `f` second?**

```
setTimeout(f, 2000);
```

In this case you have set the timeout whilst the value of `f` is still the function that prints `f`. You have not made a reference to the variable `f`, only passed its current value. Changing the value of `f` afterwards doesn't change the value that was previously passed in; that remains the `f`-printing function.

(Value-versus-reference is something that most currently-popular programming languages obscure a bit, but at least in JavaScript, there's nothing special about the fact that some of the values in question are Function objects.)

Comment: bobince - the knife of clarity +1

Answer (score 0):

1) `setTimeout()` takes a ptr to `Function` object as a first parameter.

Like you expect

```
function strlen(s) {
    var f = function() { alert(s.length); };
    return setTimeout(f, 1000);

var s1 = "xx";
strlen(s1);
s1 = "yyy";
```

to alert length of `"xx"`, not of `"yyy"`.

2) `var h = function() { f() };` uses closure of `var f`. Object stored in `f` is "read" when `h()` is called.

Comment: @synapse: `setTimeout()` queues the call of **stored** function (stored ptr to function). At this point `setTimeout()` behavior is completely clear.

Comment: there're no pointers, no threads, no signals, no semaphors, no forks or whatever here. So here it is never clear.

Comment: @synapse: All values in javascript are pointers (like in Java, Python, etc). If you pass a variable by argument then it is passed "by value" (by ptr). If you use in your function a variable that was declared outside then a closure is created. Closures in javascript are a bit strange - but there's nothing to do.